# Django Haystack two models search exclude results based on other

Tags: django, django-haystack

I have two models, based on what I want to build my search. Another one is accommodation and another is reservation. SearchQuery is returning result from both, but I would like to exclude all the accommodation search results that has a record in reservation table during x time period.

Is there a way in haystack to deal this kind of a task?

Comment: Perhaps overriding the SearchQuerySet may help http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html , or overriding the default "objects" on your model to use a manager instead  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers ?

Comment: can you post your models to clarify?